# Jquery, how to call backbone.view.extend function

Tags: jquery, backbone-views

I tried events load or ready for run the search: function(event), when page loaded cannot take effect, , but keyon is ok to do the search function.
can i call search function outside? is possibe to call page load? please make a help and i am beginner of jquery.

```
directory.views.SearchPage = Backbone.View.extend({

templateLoader: directory.utils.templateLoader,
EmployeeListView: directory.views.EmployeeListView,

initialize: function() {
  this.template = _.template(this.templateLoader.get('search-page'));
},

render: function(eventName) {
  $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
  this.listView = new directory.views.EmployeeListView({el: $('ul', this.el), model:this.model});
  this.listView.render();
  return this;
},
events: {
  "keyup .search-key": "search",
  "load .search-key": "search",
  "ready .search-key": "search"
},
// Start the search function
search: function(event) {
  var key = $('.search-key').val();
  this.model.findByName(key);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `events` hash only listens for events that happen on/in your view.

You'll need to manually subscribe to `document.ready`

```
initialize: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.template = _.template(this.templateLoader.get('search-page'));

    $(document).ready(function (event) {
        self.search(event);
    });
}
```

Comment: ethagnawl, your mean is modify the initialize: function, add the document.ready function inside? but after i tried, page load still not run the search function...am i miss something?

Comment: Yes - that's what I mean. I'd have to see the rest of your code to know if you're missing something. Are there any errors in your console? See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mCPm8/1/) Fiddle based on your code.

Comment: that really work there, i missing something last night! thanks a lot there!

Comment: may i ask you something, i try add the $(document).ready cannot put in render: function(events) ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... could you create a Fiddle that shows what you're trying to do?